# Passing parameters into jComboBox

Tags: java, user-interface

I am building a drop down box that displays names from an external database. Unfortunately I am getting an error stating

Incompatible types: DefaultListModel cannot be converted to ComboBoxModel.

The line of code giving me a problem is

```
jComboBoxProjectNumber.setModel(readDb.Connect(1));
```

readDb.Connect(1) passes a code, 1, and returns all the names in the form of a  DefaultListModel.

Comment: The error message tells you in an unambiguous way exactly what's wrong. Note as an aside, method names should begin with a lower-case letter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new ComboBoxModel from the data returned by your database. The method you are using is returning a DefaultListModel instead.

Comment: Netbeans writes it as such:         jComboBoxProjectNumber.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "item1", "item2" }));
I was under the assumption that DefaultListModel returned the format { "item1", "item2" }. However when I use         jComboBoxProjectNumber.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(readDb.Connect(1));
I get the same error. readDb has already been initialized.

Comment: Read the error. Look at the objects. Look at the javadoc for the objects. Write some code that takes the object you have and creates the object you need.